# How to make sure that deleting files inside VMs reflect in the corresponding .img file in the host server?

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I have a VM created in a server whose maximum device space is 500GB. 
The size of the VM's .img file is 33GB.

First, I copied a file of size ~3GB to the VM (in /tmp). When I did this, I could see the size of the .img file growing to 36GB in the server.

Second, I deleted the copied file. But, in the server, the .img file is not shrinking. I understand that the VM can grow until 500GB since that is the disk space. But, if there is a way to make sure that the .img file is shrunken periodically, that would be better.

I have already tried virt-sparsify, but the newly created image has a few corrupted files (for example, device mapper files) and qemu-img resize, which was unsuccessful.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: with a VM ..it is usually set up as a dynamic disc .. so .. it will grow as files get added .. what is the size of the VM ... when you set the VM up you had to choose the size of the hard drive .. the file size will grow to that size unless you manually shrink it ... if it's a Virtualbox .. there are commands that I can go through on how to shrink it ..but if you made the vm with a HDD  size of 450GB the file will never go above 450GB .. in other words .. the file will grow but wont shrink on its own

Comment: I don't know details on how your VM handles dynamically sized disk images, but when you normally delete a file inside the VM (e.g. with `rm`), that does not delete the data from the disk/image, it only marks those areas as available for overwriting. Sparse files - as which the image is stored on the host - IIRC work by only storing the "data" parts of the file, where you have non-zero bytes. Larger sequences of zero-bytes are saved as "hole" and don't take up space. I don't know if this leads my to the right conclusion, but my guess would be that you have to zero out the free space in the VM.

Comment: You need to understand that "deleting" a file does not delete it, it simply marks those blocks as free. You would need to overwrite them with something like zerofree before being able to reduce the image size.